# rails3 caching: expire_action with parameters cached by caches_action(GET)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, action-caching

I'm working on a search feature that when typing something make an ajax call to get the results. I wanna caches the search action with search keywords in memory_cache, so i make it like this:

```
# caches_action with GET parameters

caches_action :search_posts, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }
```

My question is how can i expire the action with parameters too? Is there another way to make my feature works?

Comment: Rails.clear worked, but not appropriate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to expire this kind of cache.

First one (simpler one) is to add :expires_in option to your caches_action statement - for example:

```
caches_action :search_posts, :cache_path => Proc.new { |c| c.params }, :expires_in => 16.hours.to_i
```

This will automatically expire this key after some time.

Or you can expire this cache using expire_action method from controller. It should be like:

```
expire_action :action => 'posts', :q => 'query'
```

given you have requested this page with one parameter q=query .

You can read more [in the official documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/caching_with_rails.html#action-caching) .